# Ingress behind LoadBalancer X-Forwared-For routing

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Our nginx ingress controller is behind a loadbalancer.
The Loadbalancer ist setting the the origing Host in the X-Forwarded-For Headers.
For example: "x-forwarded-host": "www.portal-app.de".

I have have also set use-forwarded-headers: "true"  in ingress.

My Ingress Rule:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kd-portal-ingress
  namespace: kd-portal-prod
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.portal-app.de
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-portal-app
          servicePort: 5050
```

When i call the Url we get allways the nginx default 404 Page.

It try too explain the scenario. [www.portal-app.de](http://www.portal-app.de) is landing on a apache loadbalancer. This LB will proxy the request to the ip where k8s and ingresscontroller is running. The proxy set the origin host infos in the x-forward headers. My Rule does not have any effect, i am allways hitting the default backend

Is it possible to define a hostbased routing behind a loadbalancer in ingress?

Comment: I think it would be more complex than just setting use-forwarded-headers: "true" , take a look at this [example](https://geko.cloud/forward-real-ip-to-a-nginx-behind-a-gcp-load-balancer/). There is related [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#enable-real-ip) about that in kubernetes ingress documentation. Additionally take a look [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#source-ip-address). Could you try with that and let me know if it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by activating the apache directive https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost

Answer (score 0):

Yes ingress primary usage is for that only. You specify domains in rules. As you can see it rule in an array, so you can add many domains and it will redirect on the backend service you specified.Also You can create seperate ingress objects too.

Example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: your_domain_name
    http:
    paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: your_service_name
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - your_domain_name
    secretName: tls-certificate
```

Comment: when i define a rule via local hostname and call the url via internal hostname it works well. Whenn ein call www.portal-app.de we receive 404
any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: what is the ip mapped to www.portal-app. If its not pointing towards IP of your loadbalancer service's IP then request is not coming to your cluster. If you are doing everything locally then you can set IP and host mapping in /etc/hosts file. Otherwise if you are doing this cloud then you have to point domain to resolve to your load balacer domain name or ip . Hope that clears things up.

Comment: Is not clear for me. It try too explain the scenario. www.portal-app.de is landing on a apache loadbalancer. This LB will proxy the request to the ip where k8s and ingresscontroller is running. The origin host infos are then set in the x-forward headers via LB. My Rule does not have any effect, i am allways hitting the default backend.